# How can save all the outputs in json file with python

Tags: python, json, python-3.6

I want save my outputs in an json file. I have a dataframe with 100 rows and 20 items columns, with one column name `ID`. In some part of my code I define the function

```
def function1(dataframe, ID):
    df_sum = dataframe.sum()
    df_sum = df_sum .sort_values(ascending=False)
    df_sum = pd.DataFrame(df_sum , columns=['num_%s'%ID])
    result_sum = df_sum .to_json(orient='columns')

    return result_sum
```

Then, my code follow with

```
for num in list(dataframe.['ID'].values):
   ...some code lines, to drop and merge columns, which create the...
   ...dataframe df_aux
   values = function1(df_aux, ID)
   print(values)
```

The Output is, (num is in the list [0,1, ..., 99], of the IDs)

```
{"num_1":{"item1":4}}
{"num_2":{"item19":6,"item20":4,"item18":4}}
...
{"num_99":{"item18":5,"item21":4,"item20":1}}
```

Now, I add the json dump function, of the following way

```
for num in list(dataframe.['ID'].values):
   ...some code lines, to drop and merge columns, which create the...
   ...dataframe df_aux
   values = function1(df_aux, ID)
   print(values) 

with open('data.json', 'w') as outfile:
   json.dump(values, outfile)
```

But the previous code, only returns the last result. When I open the `data.json` file, it only appears `"{"num_99":{"item18":5,"item21":4,"item20":1}}"`

And **I need save all the values in a json file**. I'm new with python. Any hint will be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You are getting just the last row because you are overwriting the value every iteration of the for loop.

What you can do is declare an array called `values` and append each value. Something like this:

```
values = []
for num in list(dataframe.['ID'].values):
   # some code lines, to drop and merge columns, which create the
   # dataframe df_aux
   value.append( function1(df_aux, ID) )

with open('data.json', 'w') as outfile:
   json.dump(values, outfile)
```